# Асинхронные JQuery $.ajax запрос.

Tags: ajax, php, асинхронность

Здравствуйте
Делаю загрузку файлов через Ajax, при помощи плагина jQuery-File-Upload
И с периодичностью нужно отправлять запросы на сервер с целью определения обработки файла (  это CSV файл и его нужно сначала обработать ).
Суть такого:
Загружается файл и после загрузки он обрабатывается и отдается ссылка на конечный файл.

Проблема:
Обработка может длится несколько минут и нужно каждные 3-5 сек давать запрос скрипту об этапе обработки. И запрос об этапе обрабоки ждет пока сама обработка не окончиться.   Как мне быть ?

Comment: в обработчике отключайте буферизацию вывода и прогресс сообщайте в тот же поток. http://ajaxpatterns.org/HTTP_Streaming

Иной способ - сообщать о прогрессе в базу данных, вторым запросом обращаться к этой базе и показывать текущий прогресс. 

**скриншотНеНужен**

Ещё момент - если вы делаете это через FILE API, то можно не записывать файл на стороне сервера а сразу в принимающем потоке его обрабатывать, тогда вроде как прогресс можно выводить получая прогресс запроса.

Comment: >Иной способ - сообщать о прогрессе в базу данных, вторым запросом обращаться к этой базе и показывать текущий прогресс.   
                      >>Так и делаю. Но проблема в том что запрос второй ожидает завершение первого запроса.

Answer (score 2):

Дело в том, что происходит блокировка файла сессии. Вот кусок из документации PHP:

> Сессии, использующие файлы (по умолчанию в PHP), блокируют файл сессии
>   сразу при открытии сессии функцией session_start() или косвенно при
>   указании session.auto_start. После блокировки, ни один другой скрипт
>   не может получить доступ к этому же файлу сессии, пока он не будет
>   закрыт или при завершении скрипта или при вызове функции
>   session_write_close().
>
> Скорее всего это станет проблемой для сайтов, которые активно
>   используют AJAX и делают несколько одновременных запросов. Простейшим
>   путем решить эту проблему будет вызов функции session_write_close()
>   сразу же как только все требуемые изменения в сессии будут сделаны,
>   предпочтительно ближе к началу работы скрипта. Также можно
>   использовать другой механизм сессии, который поддерживает конкурентный
>   доступ.

Сразу вызываем `session_write_close();` чтобы разблокировать файл сессии после записи в него информации по процессу загрузки. 
Далее, когда нужно изменить какой-либо параметр в сессии делаем так:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['process_state'] = $process_state;
session_write_close();
```